# Trouble loading a subset of custom application.yml configurations to a Map in Quarkus

Tags: java, yaml, quarkus, microprofile, eclipse-microprofile-config

I'm trying to use quarkus yaml extension as my main source for configs and I was trying to figure out what the best approach is for loading a map from the yaml file.

The `application.yml`:

```
quarkus:
  http:
    port: 8080
configuration:
  value:
    name1: test1
    name2: test2
    name3: test3
```

In the code I tried to inject the config value like this:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "configuration.value")
Values value;
```

Where Values contains a custom Eclipse Microprofile Converter. The converter looks like this:

```
public class ValueConverter implements Converter<Values> {
    @Override
    public Values convert(String value) {
        // Here there would be the actual code to convert to Map.
        return new Values(map);
    }
}
```

The problem is that String value comes empty, ie, it does not loading the stull below configuration.value:

```
name1: test1
name2: test2
name3: test3
```

I've also tried annotating a class with `@ConfigProperties(prefix = "configuration.value")` and have a map inside but then it does not know how to map that to a `Map` as expected... Is there a way to create custom config properties converter?

Is this a Eclipse Microprofile issue? Is this a bug? Is this a feature request? :)
Or, is there another/better way of doing this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As has been answered on the mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/quarkus-dev/oTHlRdDO7RE), this is not something supported by Eclipse MicroProfile Config - and therefore Quarkus